# The value of an integral of a piecewise defined function

Tags: calculus

I have been given $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 4 & 2\le x<5\\ 3 & x=5\end{cases}$$

and I want to find the value of $$\int_2^5 f(x) dx.$$
I proceeded as follows:  $$\int_2^5 f(x) dx  = 4(5-2) = 12. $$ But then I don't know what to do with the part  $f(x) =3, x =5.$ Any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of a function at any single point of the integral doesn't matter in the value of the integral. So, don't worry about the fact that $f(x) = 3$ at $x = 5$ since it doesn't change the value of the integral.

If you continue your math studies, you will learn that the value doesn't matter on any set with measure zero, which includes countably infinite sets like the integers.